# radio buttons in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, radio-button

I'm using knockout and I have 2 radio buttons, when a particular one is selected I need a textbox to be enabled and disabled if the other option is selected. I can't seem to get this working. this is what i have so far: IssercentageBased is a boolean on my viewmodel and i've set it up to be an observable. any ideas?

```
<input type="radio" name="IsPercentageBased" value="true" data-bind="checked: IsPercentageBased"/>
            <span>Percentage</span>
            <input type="radio" name="IsPercentageBased" value="false" data-bind="checked: IsPercentageBased"/>
            <span>Value</span>

 @Html.TextBox("Value", "", new
                {
                    type = "text",
                    data_bind = "value: Value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', disable: IsPercentageBased"
                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update data-bind attribute of text box to this:

```
data_bind = "value: Value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', disable: IsPercentageBased() == 'true'"
```

`Checked` binding sets to observable value of `Value` attribute and that is `string` to a `bool`.

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/wDRuG/